# работа функции getchar() в цикле while

Tags: c, функции, циклы

Есть вот такая вот функция:

```
int function(){ 
  int n;
  while(!scanf("%d",&n))
  {
    printf("You didn't enter a number. Try again.\n");
    while((n=getchar())!='\n');
  }
  return n;
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, каким образом работает вложенный цикл while, и как вся эта конструкция зацикливается.
Я не совсем понимаю, например, что делает (n=getchar())!='\n', и что происходит при повторном вводе. Какая строка срабатывает?

Comment: Если не считать, что эта конструкция зациклится во внутреннем while при конце файла (потока ввода) если там нет `'\n'` (да и вообще, конец файла не обрабатыватся, функция вернет неизвестто каккое значение), то работет это след. образом -- поскольку `scanf()` возвращает 1, если число успешно введено, то внутрь внешнего while мы войдем, если первый вводимый символ не цифра. Внутренний while будет считывать символы по одному и сравнивать их с `'\n'`. Как только прочли `'\n'` внутренний while завершится и мы опять вызовем scanf для чтения с начала новой строки.

Comment: Кстати, даже после внешнего while желательно проверить, какой символ идет в потоке после введенного числа (и м.б. вернуться опять к внешенму scanf), поскольку ввод типа `2q34` вряд ли можно считать правильным числом. В подобном случае scanf прочтет `2` и оставит в потоке ввода `q34`